# jqgrid prevent onSelectRow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have custom button in jqGrid cell.

On click it calls attached funcion as suposed, but after that it rises jqGrid onSelectRow event.

How to prevent onSelectRow from rising?

I need that event on every other cell in row.

Comment: Please post some codes where you think that needs help.

Answer (score 2):

If you define the event handler [beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) which return sometime `false` it will prevent the row selection and of cause prevent throwing of the `onSelectRow` event.

Comment: Sry, but I like my way better. In may case row stay selected (this is good), but my onSelectRow method just do nothing.

Comment: @SpoksST: I don't understand why you ask a question if you have a solution which you like? The usage of `beforeSelectRow` is a standard way to prevent onSelectRow from rising. What do you do in the custom `click` event handler can be done independend. I can not be more exact because you don't post any code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the right way, but my solution was to add boolean, which indicates, if custom button was pressed. 
If it is true, then I just exit onSelectRow function and set boolean to false.

Comment: it is better if you append your original question with new information (you can modify your question every time) or you white a comment to another comment or answer. Bitter write one more answer only in the case if you found the solution of your problem yourself.